# Matplotlib: Asymetric error bar for one bar in bar plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, errorbar

I want to plot 2 values in a bar plot. The second value shall have an asymetric error bar. What am I doing wrong?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

observed = 23
simulated = [18, 21, 25, 27, 20.5]
diff = [(x - np.mean(simulated)) for x in simulated]

y = [observed, np.mean(simulated)]
err_min = np.min(diff)
err_max = np.max(diff)

x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(y)]

plt.bar(x_pos, y, yerr=[[0, 0], [err_min, err_max]])
```

**Edit:** The result I get is, that both bars get an yerror (left one min and right one max). Instead I want an asymetric one only for the right bar (min and max of the simulated values).

Comment: Can you share any error messages?

Comment: Please see the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html): `shape(2, N): Separate - and + values for each bar. First row contains the lower errors, the second row contains the upper errors.` Also, these values should be >= 0, not negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by setting yerr like follows:

```
    plt.bar(x_pos, y, yerr=[[0, 0-err_min], [0, err_max]])
```